# Creates a new dictionary consisting of another dictionary key and two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary consisting of `key` (key of dictionary `x`), `Calc_1` and `Calc_2`

As you can see, there is already an older dictionary called `x` (x is not important for the purpose of the question). Dictionary x generates Calc_1 and Calc_2 for each of its keys. This works correctly.

Now i would like to group the variables `Calc_1` and `Calc_2` and each corresponding `key` into a new dictionary. So I would like to create a `newdict` dictionary that contains
`key`, (key of dictionary x) and `Calc_1` and `Calc_2`. How can i?

```
newdict = {}

for key, value in x.items():
    Calc_1= sum(value[4]) / len(value[4])
    Calc_2 = (Calc_1 *100) / 2
  
    if Calc_1 > 0.5:
        if key not in newdict:
            newdict[key] = list([key, Calc_1, Calc_2])
            newdict[key][Calc_1] = [newdict[key][Calc_1]]
        else:
            newdict[key][Calc_1].append(Calc_2)

print(newdict)
```

I get the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float`, but surely the problem will be another

Comment: It might help considerably to know what you're hoping to achieve. As it is, this has a whiff of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) about it.

Comment: @Chris I hope to get a second dictionary with 3 contents. A key which would be the dictionary key x, and two values which would be Calc_1 and Calc_2

Comment: Yes, but _why_ is the question I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Calc_1` is the average that was calculated earlier, so it's a `float`, which can't be used as a list index.

But there's no reason why you should be indexing `newdict[key]` in the first place. It's just a list of 3 elements that you created on the previous line, why would you be indexing it dynamically?

Just create the list in the new dictionary. There's no need for the `if` check since keys are unique.

```
        newdict[key] = [key, Calc_1, Calc_2]
```

Comment: Is this "still" a dictionary you created, or is it a list? If yes, can I access each of its values normally (3 in this case)?

Comment: `newdict` is still a dictionary. Its values are lists.

Comment: If this isn't right, can you update the question to show sample input and the desired result?

Comment: That's what I wanted to achieve :) I voted. Thank you. I'll have to use this code on thousands and thousands of data points in the database. I wanted to use pandas, but honestly pandas are not for this case. So I worry a lot about speed performance. I know that dictionaries are more performant than lists and tuples. Is my code, so the one you improved for me, performant for thousands of data points even if the values inside the dictionary are lists? Or can something be written faster or better? Thank you

Comment: pandas is appropriate for for equal size rows, but this has variable-sized rows, so dictionary of lists seems appropriate.

Comment: There was no need for the link. So that I have to accept your answer. Don't worry :) I was just waiting for your confirmation comment that it's the best code in my case. Can my code be improved with some minor modifications? For example remove other or something similar? Thank you

Comment: PART 1. I have a problem with the code in your answer.I hope you will answer me.Problem is caused by else: newdict[key].append(Calc_2). Your response code is contained in a checkbox.If I check or uncheck the checkbox, I print results correctly.Everything is ok.However,if I select and deselect it repeatedly and quickly with a mouse click, then I have a problem: Calc_2 repeats 16 times with the message Squeezed text (65 lines).For example {'Tokyo-Osaka': [0.5, 125.0, 125.0, 125.0 etc.]. 0.5 is Calc_1, while 125.0 is Calc_2. As you see, it just repeats Calc_2. Key and Calc_1 do not repeat

Comment: PART 2. I tried deleting else: newdict[key].append(Calc_2) and I don't have this problem anymore: everything seems ok now. But I don't know if it's the right solution. If I delete the above line, what happens to my dictionary? Why insert an append(Calc_2) if I already have Calc_2 in [key, Calc_1, Calc_2]? Thank you

Comment: This code is only designed to be run once, because it only adds `Calc_1` when it's first creating a new key.

Comment: Is this supposed to be nested dictionaries, with `Calc_1` as the key of the inner dict?

Comment: the newdict dictionary key is "key", which is also the same as the X dictionary key. Calc_1 is not the key, but it is a value. What should I do to fix the problem? If I delete else: newdict[key].append(Calc_2) the problem seems solved, but I'm not sure if the code is written well if I delete else: newdict[key].append(Calc_2), or maybe it's written well. I do not know. How do you suggest? I simply need newdict to be a dictionary composed of: key, Calc_1, Calc_2. I still point out that the "key" of newdict is also the same key of the X dictionary. Thanks

Comment: Your comment is too long and rambling for me to understand what the problem is. I asked you earlier to update the question with sample data and the desired result. Please show clearly what's happening wrong, I can't figure it out from your explanation.

Comment: I already get the desired result. I simplify my comments with a question :) If i delete "else: newdict[key].append(Calc_2)", the code seems to work fine correctly, because I still have Calc_2 in the dictionary with newdict[key] = [key, Calc_1, Calc_2]. So Calc_2 is there even if i delete "else: newdict[key].append(Calc_2)". THEN, why write "else: newdict[key].append(Calc_2)" if Calc_2 is already contained in the dictionary? I can remove the code "else: newdict[key].append(Calc_2)"?

Comment: I just realized that the `if/else` is not needed. `key` is the key of the original dictionary `x`, so they're unique. Since they can't be duplicated, there's no need to check for that.

Comment: Exactly. So I just write: newdict[key] = [key, Calc_1, Calc_2]?

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer. It was just what I said. A little curiosity: is a dictionary with the list inside it as fast and performing as a normal dictionary (without list)? Or is it slower?

Comment: Dictionaries don't care what the values are.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Also thank you for helping newbie users like me and others. Forgive the trivial questions of us beginners